# AVD-Ok button is disable while creating new android virtual device

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, android-virtual-device, eclipse-adt

I am trying to create a new Android Virtual Device from my Eclipse. I've tried almost all available answers offered here for the same question.My OK button is still disabled. I am using Android 4.4.2- API level 19. I am new to Android. Trying to make my first app. I've no idea what to do next.

Below is the screenshot. Let me know if I've done something wrong in it..

[image]

Thanks

Comment: can you able to put a screenshot of the same ?

Comment: Yes. I've just uploaded it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your screen i can tell two things,In the screen you are missing two things

> Select any device you want from the list
>
> Give memory below 700**

** on windows emulating ram more than 768M some times fail depend up on the system.

EDIT:

you can select any device from the list as you wish.If you are testing for a particular device select that one. For the first time you can select the nexus 4 that is listed first in the device and run your first app in that... happy coding

Comment: Can I test my program say simple "Hello World" without attaching any device with pc?

Comment: Then what should be my memory options? Right now I am trying to test it without attaching any device with pc. That's why didn't select any device from the list.

Comment: That is your are giving there in memory options. on windows emulating ram more than 768M some times fail depend up on the system.

Comment: But my ok button is still grayed out. I've tried different options. What to do now?

Comment: what device you have selected ?? and what is your ADT ??\

Comment: That's what I was asking you about device listing. If I want to test it in emulator then what device should be selected from the list? As I can see options such as Nexus,tablet etc. I am trying it from Eclipse.. Downloaded "adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030" and using its sdk and eclipse.

Comment: Yes just seen your edited answer. I've installed system image for the specific.

Comment: you can select any device from the list as you wish.If you are testing for a particular device select that one. For the first time you can select the nexus 4 that is listed first in the device and run your first app in that

Comment: Oh..Thanks. Ok button is enabled now..I've selected Nexus 4 device from the list. Thnaks a lot for your help.

Comment: @RishabhSrivastava what is your problem, ask another question, will try to answer

Comment: when i try to create the device i fill up all the things correctly but the ok button is disabled so i can not create a new device....

Comment: do you ask a new question with your problem please

Answer (score 2):

First you didn't select the type of device.

Another precaution is don't use space when giving the name for the device.

Answer (score 0):

I Had the Same Problem,
and Checked Both "Snapshop" and "Host GPU", as I Unckecked one of them, the OK button activated!